# Obter USER AGENT e modificar

Tags: php, html, css, less

Estou tentando montar uma função em PHP para verificar o USER AGENT

Devo conseguir saber se está em um celular ou desktop

Após isso baseado nessa informação vou aplicar um estilo diferente para a página com meu LESS/CSS

Alguém tem alguma sugestão de como fazer?

Comment: Já ouviu falar no Sinergi\BrowserDetector ? Talvez possa ajudar

Comment: Vou olhar isso, obrigado amigo, porém queria tentar uma solução sem precisar baixar nada externo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá eu utilizo a seguinte função para verificar

```
function verificaUserAgent() {
    $user_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
    $iphone = strpos($user_agent, "iPhone");
    $android = strpos($user_agent, "Android");
    $palmpre = strpos($user_agent, "webOS");
    $ipod = strpos($user_agent, "iPod");
    $berry = strpos($user_agent, "BlackBerry");
    $symbian = strpos($user_agent, "Symbian");
    $windowsphone = strpos($user_agent, "Windows Phone");

    if ($iphone || $android || $palmpre || $ipod || $berry || $symbian || $windowsphone == true) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Então no meu HTML eu faço da seguinte forma para utilizar o retorno da função

```
<html class="<?= verificaUserAgent() === true ? 'mobile' : 'desktop' ?>">
```

Por sua vez no seu arquivo LESS ou CSS eu crio uma classe principal de estilo `.mobile` e outra `.desktop` então coloco todos os estilos diferentes dentro dessas classes

Espero poder ajudar abraço!

Comment: Nossa Fabio, funcionou perfeitamente, muito obrigado pela sua solução, como vcs são rápidos, grande dia para você!

Comment: Que bom que pude te ajudar @ManeiroJR, eu tinha a função pronta uso em meus projetos aqui, se a minha solução respondeu sua dúvida marca ela como a resposta certa, um abraço!

Comment: Ele não deixou aceitar sua resposta não intendi